# Is there a command to send Windows Error Reports (WER)?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows

Is there a command that will Report All Queued Windows Error Reports? This can be done manually by going to the Action Center->Expanding Maintenance->Clicking Check For Solutions, we'd like to automate this process for our server farms (a combination of 2008R2/2012R2 Servers).

Answer (score 4):

[This option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754364.aspx) is available in Server Manager.

On Windows Server 2008 R2, scroll down to the **Resources and Support** section, and click **Turn on Windows Error Reporting**. Then choose **Yes, automatically send detailed reports** or **Yes, automatically send summary reports**.

[image: Windows Error Reporting in Server 2008 R2]

In Server 2012 R2, the option is also in Server Manager. Click on **Local Server** (or a specific server). Click on the word **On** or **Off** next to **Windows Error Reporting**. Then your choices are the same as above.

[image: Windows Error Reporting in Server 2012 R2]

---

These options can also be [set in Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618323.aspx), which is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, while this is helpful information, However I am still looking for a way to send reports that have already accumulated on a box (ideally via a command or Powershell Cmdlet).

Comment: That's a good question. I couldn't find anything. The Powershell cmdlets only turn it on and off or display its status.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this command will trigger the Check for Solutions function:

```
RunDll32.exe "C:\Windows\system32\WerConCpl.dll", LaunchErcApp -updatecheck
```

This came via Process Monitor - Tested on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 10.

There is no documentation available for this as far as I know.

It is also user sensitive (i.e. it won't send reports queued under other users).

Not sure whether this will help automation-wise as it's still a GUI-based function.

I went looking, but couldn't find any API for this (WER's API seems to be more geared for developers creating their own WER reports rather than managing the built-in system).

Comment: Thank you, while this information is helpful to doing "poor mans" automation, I'm still hoping that one day we'll find the actual call required to automating the sending of these reports!